# Data structure with O(1) lookup time which will allow duplicates

Tags: c#, .net, performance, data-structures, collections

My goal is to create a data structure implementing `IList<T>` interface which will achieve `O(1)` element lookup time by compromising memory.

**Background**
As you know all array based `IList<T>` implementations like `List<T>` have `O(n)` element lookup time. It means that the operations like `int IndexOf(T element)` or `bool Contains(T element)` iterate through the underlaying array until they find a match.

Well known idea achive that is to use a combination of a list and hashtable as underlaying data structures. Values are kept in a list. The hashtable will keep indexes as values and values of list as keys. So lookup can be performed using hashtable.

That's exactly how the `KeyedCollection<TKey, TItem>` [see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438.aspx) is implemented.

**What I have tried so far**

```
internal class MyList<T> : KeyedCollection<T, T>
{
    protected override T GetKeyForItem(T item)
    {
        return item;
    }
}
```

This worked so far except one problem. This data structure does not mimic the behavior expected behind `List<T>` exactly. The point is that the `List<T>` allows duplicates, `MyList` does not.

**Question**

Is there any ready to use data structure or can you recommend an elegant way of implementing the `IList<T>` so that:

1. Lookup operations have `O(1)` time.
2. All other operations have same `O()` performance as `List<T>`
3. Memory can be compromised by hashtable overhead (`constantA + constantB * n` bytes).
4. **Duplicates must be allowed**
5. Allowing nulls is optional (they can be boxed into null objects)

Comment: What do you mean by "duplicates must be allowed". Do you need to keep each instance of the duplicate, ignore the duplicate, overwrite the duplicate?

Comment: I think the trickiest piece of this will be matching the definition of `IndexOf` that states: "If an object occurs multiple times in the list, the IndexOf method always returns the first instance found."

Comment: You keep comparing your data structure to a `List` and a `Set` at the same time.  Not only does performance differ between the two, but the APIs differ greatly.  Sets are unordered, lists are ordered, and that makes a *big* difference.  Will you collection be ordered?  Having a set/map that allows duplicates is called a "bag" (which is still unordered).  Having a List that has O(1) search speed just doesn't exist.

Comment: Duplicates = multiple value for the same key? If so, the `.ToLookup` extension method on `IEnumerable<T>` is a nice one, but it's read-only so after calling it, you can't add items. That might not be what you want though.

Comment: Behave exactly like the `List<T>` behaves when you add the "same" object twice. With "same" I mean equivalent in terms of `Equals` & `GetHashCode` implementations.

Comment: @achitaka-san Okay, but should it be ordered? A list is ordered, sets/dictionaries aren't.

Comment: @delnan Yes, the order (and index access `this[index]`) is essential.

Comment: @achitaka-san Then it's not possible.  Done.

Comment: @Servy - Yes I am aware of performance differences between different data structures and they API differences. I need `IList` API having O(1) lookup time. I can easyly reach that as I showed with only one drawback - no duplicates.

Comment: @achitaka-san No you can't.  If you're using a dictionary/hash table then you don't have an ordered collection, you have an unordered collection.  The key reason that hash based data structures can have such fast search/add/remove times is * precisely because they're not ordered*.  Adding the restriction that the collection be ordered removes the possibility of using those types of collections.

Comment: @Servy - we'll see. We have a least one solution see below.

Comment: @achitaka-san No, you don't.  None of the solutions below meet all of your requirements.  Apparently at least some of the things you've specifically said are requirements aren't actually requirements (I'm still trying to figure out which ones).

Comment: `Remove` has to allow `O(m)` where `m` is the number of duplicates.

Comment: @sixlettervariables agree but it's still `O(1)` it duplicates are rare.

Comment: @achitaka-san Removing items from a list is O(n), not O(1).  Removing an item from this special list would be, at best, O(n*m) where n is the size of the entire list an m is the number of duplicates.

Comment: Best case scenario you marry a `Dictionary<T,LinkedList<T>>` and `List<LinkedListNode<T>>`. Horrific to handle things like `dictMapListHashStructKerfloovy[17] = newValue;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on what `Ryan Bennett` has proposed, I think the best you are going to come up with (as you state order is important) is to create a class that implements IList and then internally has something like this:

```
class MyList<T> : IList<T>
{
    Dictionary<T, List<int>> _indexMap;
    List<T> _items;


    public int IndexOf(T item)
    {
        List<int> indices;
        if(_indexMap.TryGetValue(item, out indices))
        {
            return indices[0];
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        List<int> indices;
        if(!_indexMap.TryGetValue(item, out indices))
        {
            indices = new List<int>();
            _indexMap[item] = indices;
        }

        indices.Add(_items.Count);
        _items.Add(item);
    }

    // Attempt at a Remove implementation, this could probably be improved
    // but here is my first crack at it
    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        List<int> indices;
        if(!_indexMap.TryGetValue(item, out indices))
        {
            // Not found so can just return false
            return false;
        }

        int index = indices[0];
        indices.RemoveAt(0);
        if (indices.Count == 0)
        {
            _indexMap.Remove(item);
        }

        for(int i=index+1; i < _items.Count; ++i)
        {
            List<int> otherIndexList = _indexMap[_items[i]];
            for(int j=0; j < otherIndexList.Count; ++j)
            {
                int temp = otherIndexList[j];
                if (temp > index)
                {
                    otherIndexList[j] = --temp;
                }
            }
        }

        return _items.RemoveAt(index);
    }

    // ... Other similar type functions here
}
```

Edit:

Just realized that things get real sticky here when you do a `Remove`. You will have to walk the collection of indices and update any index with a value > the index of the item you remove. You have now increased the "remove" time.  You have also made it tricky to get correct. I would throw a massive amount of unit tests around this collection if you were going to try to implement something like this.

I know you are stating order is important so I am assuming that is why you are not going wtih a Sorted list approach which would allow the duplicates and give you O(log n) operation times.

Edit 2: Another book keeping type approach
I am just bouncing this one around in my head and so I will only give some rough pseudo code but you could possibly take an approach where you just have a dictionary of items mapped to a list of indices and a second dictionary that maps indices to items. If you add the restriction that T is a class then you are only paying the overhead of two storages of the reference.  You then need to maintain a current "last" so that you can easily add a new item into the collection. This should make the remove operation a bit cleaner. It is still O(n) because you have to update anything with an index > the removed item.  In first imaginings, this seems like a potential solution that will get you close to what you want to achieve (if I am understanding the goals correctly).

Comment: Instead of a `List<int>` I'd use `LinkedList<int>`. This avoids array-shift the `List<int>` would incur when `Remove(T item)` is called on `MyList<T>` by always removing the `First` element by calling `RemoveFirst()`. :)

Comment: @hIpPy Actually a `LinkedList` would almost certainly be slower in practice.  While add/remove operations are O(1) if you have a reference to the node, search speed isn't O(1) anymore, it's O(n), and a particularly slow O(n) at that.  Linked lists lose memory logicality over array-based structures, so using them results in much slower access to items, lots more cache misses, etc.  This *dramatically* hurts performance for operations that have the same big O value as array based structures.  On top of that, the end up using quite a bit more memory thanks to memory fragmentation.

Comment: @Servy, Or the last element could be removed from the `List<int>`.

Comment: @hIpPy Not sure what you're trying to say.  Removing the last element from a `List` is O(1).  I assume you meant to say the first, as that would be O(n)?  Removing the first item from a `List` is actually quite a bit quicker than removing the last item from a `LinkedList`, despite them both being O(n).

Comment: @pstrjds - Agree. Remove requires reindexing and can not be performed in O(1). The same applies to Insert.

Comment: @pstrjds I am afraid I didn't get why O(n^2)? O(n) for insert + O(n) for update is still 2 * O(n) = O(n) and not O(n^2).

Comment: @achitaka-san - You are correct. I had originally had it as O(2*n) and then questioned myself thinking another list walk would make it n^2 - but I am wrong, it would only be O(n^2) if it was a nested list walk...thanks for pointing it out. Too late to edit my comment though so I will just delete it lest it confuse someone later.

Comment: @achitaka-san - On the upside, the original idea does meet the requirement (in the case of `Remove` and `Insert`) that the complexity matches that of `List`

Comment: I think this is probably the best solution - or at least best foundation to a solution that is proposed.

Answer (score 4):

The only way I could see this is using a dictionary of lists. Hitting the key gives you a list of all duplicates that create that particular key. Just always take the first one.

Comment: That's true if he wants a map with duplicate keys.  If he wants a set then that wouldn't work.  (He switches between the two as to what he's implying in the OP, so I have no idea which he really needs.)

Comment: Thanks. Sure it will work. I have also considered similar solution. The problem is the list overhed which will rarely contain more than one element. Still waiting for more "elegant" solution, otherwise will accept yours.

Comment: @achitaka-san So you don't need an ordered collection, despite your repeated comments indicating otherwise?

Comment: Ryan, apparently he needs an ordered collection, so this isn't an option.

Comment: @Servy - I think I start understanding you. Could you please explain us better why order is not preserved in this solution?

Comment: @achitaka-san Why would order be present in this solution?  You can't get the i-th value out of a dictionary; you can only see if a key exists, get the value associated with a key, change the value associated with the key, or remove the value associated with a key.  None of that is related to the index or order of the list, because there is none.  When iterating the structure the order returned is arbitrary and cannot be relied on to mean anything.

Answer (score 1):

The hash table should hold a list of indices for each key. And I think this is all you need,  no?

Comment: But then you don't have the proper performance for all of your methods.  Searching would be okay but not removing, as you'll need to maintain both data structures.

Answer (score 0):

If you can develop a structure with O(1) search time you will find yourself becoming very very rich :p

Basically this type of structure doesn't exist, the closest this to this is a [Hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)

C# has a built in hash table type - [C~ Hash Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx)

Comment: The entire premise of the OP is that he's looking for hash tables that allow duplicates; this would indicate he's familiar with the concept of a hash table already, and that it doesn't solve his problem(s).

Comment: Yes... and what he's looking for doesn't exist. Even the hash table itself doesn't have O(1) search time.

Comment: Yes, the best thing achievable here is average case O(1) lookup. In the worst case, hashtables are still O(n). That said, having an average case O(1) lookup is indeed valuable, just saying.

Comment: @EamonnMcEvoy Hash table search time *is* O(1)... in the average case. Yes, the worst case is different, but after decades of CS research and experiments that case is so rare it's rarely worth mentioning (when discussing mature real-world implementations).

Comment: @delnan Actually, the O-ness of a hash based structure is primarily based on the quality of the hash function of the key.  If you use a custom type with a custom hash function, and implement it poorly, it's quite easy to end up with O(n) access time (or even worse, if your hash function can't be computed in O(1) time).  Now, when using something like a string, or other common hash keys with hash functions written by the library, you can generally trust them to be written well enough to result in (close enough to) O(1) access.

Comment: @Servy Partially. For any hash table, there are hash functions which result in O(n) lookups, and the constant hash `H(x) = c` is always bad. But part of the discoveries I was referring to have been distilled into good rules of thumb for easier creation of good hash functions. Collision resolution schemes have also evolved to cope with/embrace  hashes usually considered "bad". Obviously, a "hash function" that's comically bad will ruin your day, but I consider this to be an exception. I rarely ever implement my own hash function, despite using dictionaries and custom types all the time.